# How do I create a function that compares two players of a Fifa dataset on the columns I want?

Tags: r, columnsorting

So I have a dataset with columns that include name, age and a lot more of information on the players. I am pretty new at R and programming languages in general.So, I don't know how to write code which creates a function of which (1) the input is: player1,player (players which can be found in the column "name") and of which (2) the output is: their data on the columns: Name, age, overall, position and 6 different skill ratings(depending on the player's position on the field the output should be different(See the 6 data points needed for goalkeepers and the 6 data point needed for any other position in the script below). In a column named "Class" we can retrieve information about whether is a "Goalkeeper" or not. The rows in that column are filled with the variables "Attacker", "Midfielder", "Defender" and "Goalkeeper"

I wrote this:

```
Compare_Players <- Function(Player1, Player2) {
  if ((Player1 == "Goalkeeper")) {
    print(
      Name,
      Age,
      Overall,
      Position,
      GKDiving,
      GKHandling,
      GKKicking,
      GKPositioning,
      GKReflexes,
      Speed,
      Skill.Moves
    )
  } else{
    print(
      Name,
      Age,
      Overall,
      Position,
      Pace,
      Shooting,
      Passing,
      GeneralDribling,
      Defending,
      Physical,
      Skill.Moves
    )
  }
```

What I want the function to look like in use: `Compare_Players(Messi,Ronaldo)`

Outcome: both their data on the above mentioned columns

#reprex (output of >dput(head(df1, 20))

```
structure(list(Name = c("L. Messi", "Cristiano Ronaldo", "Neymar Jr", 
"De Gea", "K. De Bruyne", "E. Hazard", "L. Modrić", "L. Suárez", 
"Sergio Ramos", "J. Oblak", "R. Lewandowski", "T. Kroos", "D. Godín", 
"David Silva", "N. Kanté", "P. Dybala", "H. Kane", "A. Griezmann", 
"M. ter Stegen", "T. Courtois"), Age = c(31L, 33L, 26L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 32L, 31L, 32L, 25L, 29L, 28L, 32L, 32L, 27L, 24L, 24L, 
27L, 26L, 26L), Nationality = c("Argentina", "Portugal", "Brazil", 
"Spain", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Croatia", "Uruguay", "Spain", 
"Slovenia", "Poland", "Germany", "Uruguay", "Spain", "France", 
"Argentina", "England", "France", "Germany", "Belgium"), Overall = c(94L, 
94L, 92L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L), Potential = c(94L, 94L, 93L, 93L, 
92L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 93L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 94L, 91L, 
90L, 92L, 90L), Club = c("FC Barcelona", "Juventus", "Paris Saint-Germain", 
"Manchester United", "Manchester City", "Chelsea", "Real Madrid", 
"FC Barcelona", "Real Madrid", "Atlético Madrid", "FC Bayern München", 
"Real Madrid", "Atlético Madrid", "Manchester City", "Chelsea", 
"Juventus", "Tottenham Hotspur", "Atlético Madrid", "FC Barcelona", 
"Real Madrid"), Value = c(110500000, 7.7e+07, 118500000, 7.2e+07, 
1.02e+08, 9.3e+07, 6.7e+07, 8e+07, 5.1e+07, 6.8e+07, 7.7e+07, 
76500000, 4.4e+07, 6e+07, 6.3e+07, 8.9e+07, 83500000, 7.8e+07, 
5.8e+07, 53500000), Wage = c(565000, 405000, 290000, 260000, 
355000, 340000, 420000, 455000, 380000, 94000, 205000, 355000, 
125000, 285000, 225000, 205000, 205000, 145000, 240000, 240000
), Preferred.Foot = c("Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Right", 
"Right", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Right", 
"Right", "Left", "Right", "Left", "Right", "Left", "Right", "Left"
), International.Reputation = c(5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 
4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4), Weak.Foot = c(4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2), Skill.Moves = c(4, 
5, 5, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1), Work.Rate = c("Medium/ Medium", 
"High/ Low", "High/ Medium", "Medium/ Medium", "High/ High", 
"High/ Medium", "High/ High", "High/ Medium", "High/ Medium", 
"Medium/ Medium", "High/ Medium", "Medium/ Medium", "Medium/ High", 
"High/ Medium", "Medium/ High", "High/ Medium", "High/ High", 
"High/ High", "Medium/ Medium", "Medium/ Medium"), Body.Type = c("Messi", 
"C. Ronaldo", "Neymar", "Lean", "Normal", "Normal", "Lean", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Lean", "Normal", "Lean", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Lean", "Normal", "Courtois"), Position = c("RF", 
"ST", "LW", "GK", "RCM", "LF", "RCM", "RS", "RCB", "GK", "ST", 
"LCM", "CB", "LCM", "LDM", "LF", "ST", "CAM", "GK", "GK"), Jersey.Number = c(10, 
7, 10, 1, 7, 10, 10, 9, 15, 1, 9, 8, 10, 21, 13, 21, 9, 7, 22, 
1), Height = c(170, 188, 175, 193, 180, 173, 173, 183, 183, 188, 
183, 183, 188, 173, 168, 178, 188, 175, 188, 198), Weight = c(72, 
83, 68, 76, 70, 74, 66, 86, 82, 87, 80, 76, 78, 67, 72, 75, 89, 
73, 85, 96), Crossing = c(84, 84, 79, 17, 93, 81, 86, 77, 66, 
13, 62, 88, 55, 84, 68, 82, 75, 82, 15, 14), Finishing = c(95, 
94, 87, 13, 82, 84, 72, 93, 60, 11, 91, 76, 42, 76, 65, 84, 94, 
90, 14, 14), HeadingAccuracy = c(70, 89, 62, 21, 55, 61, 55, 
77, 91, 15, 85, 54, 92, 54, 54, 68, 85, 84, 11, 13), ShortPassing = c(90, 
81, 84, 50, 92, 89, 93, 82, 78, 29, 83, 92, 79, 93, 86, 87, 80, 
83, 36, 33), Volleys = c(86, 87, 84, 13, 82, 80, 76, 88, 66, 
13, 89, 82, 47, 82, 56, 88, 84, 87, 14, 12), Dribbling = c(97, 
88, 96, 18, 86, 95, 90, 87, 63, 12, 85, 81, 53, 89, 79, 92, 80, 
88, 17, 13), Curve = c(93, 81, 88, 21, 85, 83, 85, 86, 74, 13, 
77, 86, 49, 82, 49, 88, 78, 84, 18, 19), FKAccuracy = c(94, 76, 
87, 19, 83, 79, 78, 84, 72, 14, 86, 84, 51, 77, 49, 88, 68, 78, 
12, 20), LongPassing = c(87, 77, 78, 51, 91, 83, 88, 64, 77, 
26, 65, 93, 70, 87, 81, 75, 82, 76, 42, 35), BallControl = c(96, 
94, 95, 42, 91, 94, 93, 90, 84, 16, 89, 90, 76, 94, 80, 92, 84, 
90, 18, 23), Acceleration = c(91, 89, 94, 57, 78, 94, 80, 86, 
76, 43, 77, 64, 68, 70, 82, 87, 68, 88, 38, 46), SprintSpeed = c(86, 
91, 90, 58, 76, 88, 72, 75, 75, 60, 78, 62, 68, 64, 78, 83, 72, 
85, 50, 52), Agility = c(91, 87, 96, 60, 79, 95, 93, 82, 78, 
67, 78, 70, 58, 92, 82, 91, 71, 90, 37, 61), Reactions = c(95, 
96, 94, 90, 91, 90, 90, 92, 85, 86, 90, 89, 85, 90, 93, 86, 91, 
90, 85, 84), Balance = c(95, 70, 84, 43, 77, 94, 94, 83, 66, 
49, 78, 71, 54, 90, 92, 85, 71, 80, 43, 45), ShotPower = c(85, 
95, 80, 31, 91, 82, 79, 86, 79, 22, 88, 87, 67, 72, 71, 82, 88, 
80, 22, 36), Jumping = c(68, 95, 61, 67, 63, 56, 68, 69, 93, 
76, 84, 30, 91, 64, 77, 75, 78, 90, 79, 68), Stamina = c(72, 
88, 81, 43, 90, 83, 89, 90, 84, 41, 78, 75, 66, 78, 96, 80, 89, 
83, 35, 38), Strength = c(59, 79, 49, 64, 75, 66, 58, 83, 83, 
78, 84, 73, 88, 52, 76, 65, 84, 62, 79, 70), LongShots = c(94, 
93, 82, 12, 91, 80, 82, 85, 59, 12, 84, 92, 43, 75, 69, 88, 85, 
82, 10, 17), Aggression = c(48, 63, 56, 38, 76, 54, 62, 87, 88, 
34, 80, 60, 89, 57, 90, 48, 76, 69, 43, 23), Interceptions = c(22, 
29, 36, 30, 61, 41, 83, 41, 90, 19, 39, 82, 88, 50, 92, 32, 35, 
35, 22, 15), Positioning = c(94, 95, 89, 12, 87, 87, 79, 92, 
60, 11, 91, 79, 48, 89, 71, 84, 93, 91, 11, 13), Vision = c(94, 
82, 87, 68, 94, 89, 92, 84, 63, 70, 77, 86, 52, 92, 79, 87, 80, 
83, 69, 44), Penalties = c(75, 85, 81, 40, 79, 86, 82, 85, 75, 
11, 88, 73, 50, 75, 54, 86, 90, 79, 25, 27), Composure = c(96, 
95, 94, 68, 88, 91, 84, 85, 82, 70, 86, 85, 82, 93, 85, 84, 89, 
87, 69, 66), Marking = c(33, 28, 27, 15, 68, 34, 60, 62, 87, 
27, 34, 72, 90, 59, 90, 23, 56, 59, 25, 20), StandingTackle = c(28, 
31, 24, 21, 58, 27, 76, 45, 92, 12, 42, 79, 89, 53, 91, 20, 36, 
47, 13, 18), SlidingTackle = c(26, 23, 33, 13, 51, 22, 73, 38, 
91, 18, 19, 69, 89, 29, 85, 20, 38, 48, 10, 16), GKDiving = c(6, 
7, 9, 90, 15, 11, 13, 27, 11, 86, 15, 10, 6, 6, 15, 5, 8, 14, 
87, 85), GKHandling = c(11, 11, 9, 85, 13, 12, 9, 25, 8, 92, 
6, 11, 8, 15, 12, 4, 10, 8, 85, 91), GKKicking = c(15, 15, 15, 
87, 5, 6, 7, 31, 9, 78, 12, 13, 15, 7, 10, 4, 11, 14, 88, 72), 
    GKPositioning = c(14, 14, 15, 88, 10, 8, 14, 33, 7, 88, 8, 
    7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 14, 13, 85, 86), GKReflexes = c(8, 11, 11, 
    94, 13, 8, 9, 37, 11, 89, 10, 10, 15, 12, 10, 8, 11, 14, 
    90, 88), League = c("La Liga", "Serie A", "Ligue 1", "Premier League", 
    "Premier League", "Premier League", "La Liga", "La Liga", 
    "La Liga", "La Liga", "Bundesliga", "La Liga", "La Liga", 
    "Premier League", "Premier League", "Serie A", "Premier League", 
    "La Liga", "La Liga", "La Liga"), `Country/competition` = c("Spain", 
    "Italy", "France", "UK", "UK", "UK", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
    "Spain", "Germany", "Spain", "Spain", "UK", "UK", "Italy", 
    "UK", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain"), Class = c("Forward", "Forward", 
    "Forward", "Goalkeeper", "Midfielder", "Forward", "Midfielder", 
    "Forward", "Defender", "Goalkeeper", "Forward", "Midfielder", 
    "Defender", "Midfielder", "Midfielder", "Forward", "Forward", 
    "Midfielder", "Goalkeeper", "Goalkeeper"), Pace = c(88, 90, 
    92, 58, 77, 91, 76, 80, 75, 52, 78, 63, 68, 67, 80, 85, 70, 
    86, 45, 49), Shooting = c(91, 93, 84, 18, 86, 83, 76, 89, 
    65, 14, 89, 82, 48, 76, 66, 85, 90, 86, 15, 20), Passing = c(90, 
    81, 83, 44, 92, 86, 90, 79, 72, 32, 75, 89, 65, 89, 77, 84, 
    79, 82, 37, 30), GeneralDribbling = c(96, 89, 95, 32, 87, 
    95, 92, 87, 72, 21, 85, 83, 62, 91, 80, 92, 80, 88, 21, 23
    ), Defending = c(32, 35, 32, 20, 61, 35, 70, 52, 90, 19, 
    41, 74, 89, 52, 87, 28, 47, 52, 18, 17), Physical = c(60, 
    79, 59, 54, 78, 67, 67, 85, 85, 60, 82, 69, 83, 60, 84, 66, 
    83, 70, 61, 52), Speed = c(89, 90, 92, 57, 77, 92, 77, 82, 
    76, 50, 77, 63, 68, 68, 80, 85, 70, 87, 43, 48)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please provide a reprex

Comment: You can provide a reproducible example ("reprex") by pasting here the output from `dput(head(df1, 20))`

Comment: The output was too big to comment so I edited the original post and added the output

Answer (score 1):

Without a reprex it is gueswork as to what your data looks like. Assuming you have `NA` values for variables which are not applicable to players, as in this toy data set.

```
library(tidyverse)
#df <- tibble(Name = c("Messi", "Ronaldo", "RandomGuy"),
 #            Position = c("Somewhere", "Elsehwere", "Goalkeeper"),
  #           Pace = c(999, 555, NA),
   #          GKHandling = c(NA, NA, 15)
    #         )
df <- OP's reprex
```

Then we can use the nice `rlang` package to specify arbitary number of players to compare, tidy up the data using `tidyr` and subset the data using `dplyr`.

```
Compare_Players <- function(df, ...){
  gk_stats <- c("First_name", "Surname", "Age", "Overall", "Position", "GKDiving", "GKHandling", "GKKicking", "GKPositioning", "GKReflexes", "Speed", "Skill.Moves")
  stats <- c("First_name", "Surname",  "Age", "Overall", "Position", "Pace", "Shooting", "Passing", "Defending", "Physical", "Skill.Moves")
  
  players <- ensyms(...)
  df %>%
    extract(Name, into = c("First_name", "Surname"), "^(.* )(.*)") %>%
    filter(Surname %in% !!players) %>%
    select({if("GK" %in% .$Position) gk_stats else stats})
}
```

This allows us to write players without quotes directly in the function call.
For a detailed explanation of how this works, refer to [Advanced R][1]. Long story short - it takes arguments passed by the `...`, and converts it such that the `filter` function knows it is a character vector.

We can now call `Compare_Players(df, Messi, Ronaldo)`, which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 x 11
  First_name Surname   Age Overall Position  Pace Shooting Passing Defending Physical Skill.Moves
  <chr>      <chr>   <int>   <int> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>
1 L.         Messi      31      94 RF          88       91      90        32       60           4
2 Cristiano  Ronaldo    33      94 ST          90       93      81        35       79           5
```

Two caveats - if the player has a `Surname` that includes spaces, the last name segment is chosen. For this small set it is no issue, but if you have duplicates in the set you might want to apply additional filtering or fine tune the regex in the `extract` call. Finally, calling `Compare_Players(df, Messi, Gea)` returns

```
# A tibble: 2 x 12
  First_name Surname   Age Overall Position GKDiving GKHandling GKKicking GKPositioning GKReflexes Speed Skill.Moves
  <chr>      <chr>   <int>   <int> <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1 L.         Messi      31      94 RF              6         11        15            14          8    89           4
2 De         Gea        27      91 GK             90         85        87            88         94    57           1
```

So beware of non-informative calls, as the function will return regardless
[1]: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html

Comment: I edited my question to make it make more sense and tried to add a reprex. The data set I use is a player statistics data set of fifa19. (very easy to find if the reprex I provided isn't what you asked for) However I did compute some of the columns used in the function myself (For example, Pace(made up of Columns (1)Sprintspeed*0,55 + (2)Acceleration*0,45)).

Comment: Your `Name` column is messy. Some first names are abbreviated, others are not. An extra step needs to be added to the function to make it work again, as spaces in quasinotation does not work. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
library(tidyverse)

Compare_Players <- function(data, Player1, Player2){
  
  stats <- c("Name", "Age", "Overall", "Position", "Pace", "Shooting", "Passing", "GeneralDribling", "Defending", "Physical", "Skill.Moves",
             "GKDiving", "GKHandling", "GKKicking", "GKPositioning", "GKReflexes", "Speed", "Skill.Moves")
  
  df %>% 
    filter(Name == !!enquo(Player1) | Name == !!enquo(Player2)) %>% 
    select(any_of(stats))
}


Compare_Players(df, "L. Messi", "De Gea")
```

This gives us:

```
      Name Age Overall Position Pace Shooting Passing Defending Physical Skill.Moves GKDiving GKHandling GKKicking GKPositioning GKReflexes Speed
1 L. Messi  31      94       RF   88       91      90        32       60           4        6         11        15            14          8    89
2   De Gea  27      91       GK   58       18      44        20       54           1       90         85        87            88         94    57
```

Edit:

If you want to see two players and different stats, you can combine into a `list`, but it's a bit more complicated:

```
Compare_Players <- function(data, Player1, Player2){
  
  p1 <- data %>% 
    filter(Name == !!enquo(Player1))
  
  p2 <- data %>% 
    filter(Name == !!enquo(Player2))
  
  gk_stats <- c("Name", "Age", "Overall", "Position", "GKDiving", "GKHandling", "GKKicking", "GKPositioning", "GKReflexes", "Speed", "Skill.Moves")
  
  stats <- c("Name", "Age", "Overall", "Position", "Pace", "Shooting", "Passing", "GeneralDribling", "Defending", "Physical", "Skill.Moves")
  
if (p1$Class == "Goalkeeper"){
  p1 <- p1 %>% select(any_of(gk_stats))
} else {
  p1 <- p1 %>% select(any_of(stats))
}
  
  if (p2$Class == "Goalkeeper"){
    p2 <- p2 %>% select(any_of(gk_stats))
  } else {
    p2 <- p2 %>% select(any_of(stats))
  }  
  
  out <- list(p1,p2)
  out
  
}
```

Which gives us:

```
> Compare_Players(df, "L. Messi", "De Gea")
[[1]]
      Name Age Overall Position Pace Shooting Passing Defending Physical Skill.Moves
1 L. Messi  31      94       RF   88       91      90        32       60           4

[[2]]
    Name Age Overall Position GKDiving GKHandling GKKicking GKPositioning GKReflexes Speed Skill.Moves
1 De Gea  27      91       GK       90         85        87            88         94    57           1
```

Comment: This is great! However, wouldn't this also print the goalkeeping skills even when comparing players two strikers for example?

Comment: Yes it would. What would you want to see if player1 was not a goalkeeper and player2 was?

Comment: Exactly that, but without printing the irrelevant stats for the corresponding player. The comparison in this case it not a comparison anymore since the stats are gathered from different columns, yes. But, I am trying to make it look as clean as possible.

Comment: Notice GeneralDribbling is not in the reprex variable names